# bootstrap 3 nested grid ignore parent?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a 2 part form. The first part, labels are col-sm-2 and the inputs are col-sm-8.

The second part, I want to do the form and some help text to the right. So I made labels col-sm-2 and inputs col-sm-6.

Then I have a ul with col-sm-4 pull-right, however it won't float right of the form.

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal col-sm-12" role="form">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Input</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Input 2</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Input 3</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 pull-right">
      <ul>
        <li>list item 1 that causes the column to wrap</li>
        <li>list item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

```
<!-- /.container -->
```

How can I get the list to float right of "Input 2" & "Input 3" in this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/BcUKRcoICC#)?

Comment: Do you really want those style applied only on small devices?

Comment: @Ron.Basco isn't it applied on sm and larger?

Comment: use `col-lg-*` for larger devices. take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

Comment: Show your code, it's much easier to understand that a description.

Comment: @DavidG added the code

Comment: @Ron.Basco thats correct if I want it to display differently across the different screen sizes, but right now I want it to display the same on all devices

Comment: why do you need it to be in bootstrap grid? this can be done using custom css only.

Comment: try using  **pull-right** class on the  **ul** instead of the div

Comment: This one: http://www.bootply.com/FzN9FtUTXu#

Comment: @kalpeshpatel This is what I was trying to do. You don't necessarily need the row classes, but it was the wrapping of the list and input html in a <div class="form-group" that did the trick. if you create an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @rodney757, I have added my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal col-sm-12" role="form">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label label-default="" class="control-label col-sm-2">Input</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="form-group  row">
                <label label-default="" class="control-label col-sm-3">Input 2</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label label-default="" class="control-label col-sm-3">Input 3</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <ul>
                <li>list item 1 that causes the column to wrap</li>
                <li>list item 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Running demo: http://www.bootply.com/FzN9FtUTXu#

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following structure instead:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Input</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
        <div class="row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Input 2</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Input 3</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <ul>
        <li>list item 1 that causes the column to wrap</li>
        <li>list item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Use bootstrap 'row' to wrap your columns and it would be good if you complete the count of columns covered in a row to '12' [as in above snippet "8+4", "10+2", "3+9"]. This would help in aligning columns properly but that totally depends on the requirement.

Comment: This was very close, it just removed the form-group from the inputs, and Input 2 & Input 3 didn't quite line up with Input 1

Comment: Yeah it just required a lit bit of alignment.